# Deduplicating e-commerce products based on title/description/images

Tags: data-cleaning

I am trying to clean a set of e-commerce data.
Data consists of products which has multiple images, a title and a description.
Some of these products has duplicates and I need to de-duplicate the set.
I have worked on NN's and Genetic Algorithms back in college but that's it.

What I need is a starting point to dive into. What methods/techniques should I use, what should I learn first?

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point [chapter 3](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf) of Mining Massive Datasets (MMDS) offers a very good introduction on document similarity. You can also look [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html). For near-duplicate image detection look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034900/near-duplicate-image-detection) on StackOverflow.

For the text data, first you have to convert your strings to a vector of features, this features could be [tf-idf vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) of all the tokens (words) that appear in the database, could also be a vector of [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). For a discussion of semantic and syntactic features you can look [here](http://www2013.org/proceedings/p1273.pdf).

Given the vectors for each product on your database you would have to compute the similarity among all pair of products. Then the most common similarities measures are [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) and [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

The brute force approach is O(n^2), where is the number of products in the database so this could be unfeasible. A common technique to deal with this issue is to use fingerprinting (hashing) together with Locality Sensitive Hashing (LSH), both techniques are discussed in chapter 3 of MMDS.